# Determine how many characters in UILabel has truncated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have an `UILabel` and I want to determine how many characters in `UILabel` has truncated.
With this code below, I can determine it if my `UILabel` only have 1 line

```
int numberOfTruncatedCharacter = 0;
NSString *text = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s";

NSArray  *words = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *newStr = @"";
for (NSString *word in words) {
    NSString *statement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",newStr, word];
    CGSize size = [statement sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.aboutLabel.font}];

    if(size.width < self.aboutLabel.bounds.size.width){
        newStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",newStr, word];
    }else{
        numberOfTruncatedCharacter++;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@ | %f | %f",word,size.width,self.aboutLabel.bounds.size.width);
}
NSLog(@"number of truncated character = %d",numberOfTruncatedCharacter);
```

It works correctly and here is the log

```
2016-05-27 10:02:44.642 EarCrush[2284:42690] Lorem | 32.622070 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.642 EarCrush[2284:42690] Ipsum | 64.345703 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.642 EarCrush[2284:42690] is | 74.243164 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.643 EarCrush[2284:42690] simply | 107.138672 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.643 EarCrush[2284:42690] dummy | 145.644531 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.643 EarCrush[2284:42690] text | 165.952148 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.644 EarCrush[2284:42690] of | 177.978516 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.644 EarCrush[2284:42690] the | 195.854492 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.645 EarCrush[2284:42690] printing | 235.004883 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.646 EarCrush[2284:42690] and | 255.429688 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.647 EarCrush[2284:42690] typesetting | 309.921875 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.648 EarCrush[2284:42690] industry. | 353.134766 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.649 EarCrush[2284:42690] Lorem | 385.756836 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.649 EarCrush[2284:42690] Ipsum | 384.858398 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.650 EarCrush[2284:42690] has | 372.202148 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.650 EarCrush[2284:42690] been | 379.218750 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.650 EarCrush[2284:42690] the | 371.010742 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.651 EarCrush[2284:42690] industry's | 401.171875 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.651 EarCrush[2284:42690] standard | 397.431641 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.652 EarCrush[2284:42690] dummy | 391.640625 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.652 EarCrush[2284:42690] text | 373.442383 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.653 EarCrush[2284:42690] ever | 375.844727 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.653 EarCrush[2284:42690] since | 379.541016 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.653 EarCrush[2284:42690] the | 371.010742 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.654 EarCrush[2284:42690] 1500s | 383.374023 | 355.000000
2016-05-27 10:02:44.654 EarCrush[2284:42690] number of truncated character = 13
```

The problem is when my `UILabel` have multiple lines, I change my code to

`if(size.width < self.aboutLabel.bounds.size.width * numberOfLines){`

However it won't calculate correctly. I think maybe when `UILabel` have multiple lines, it will contains break line character

Any idea to fix it. Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: Why would u want to know how many characters have been truncated?

Comment: @KingBabar I want to display it to user

Comment: Is it possible to you, to use a `UITextView` instead of an `UILabel`?

Comment: @PhanVănLinh : have you tried my answer? It is working fine in my demo!

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the width but you need to check the height.

Check out this open source and see how TTTAttributedLabel is using CoreText to know when to add the '...' character.

https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/blob/master/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel.m

Look at the drawframesetter:attributedstring:textrange:inrect:context: method

You can also change the open source and expose the position of '...'

Comment: Because you only check the width you disregard the line spacing which results in a bad result

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];
  UILabel *label1 = self.myLabel;


UIFont *font = label1.font;
NSString *text = @"This is the label text wich will be truncate!!";

CGRect label1Frame = label1.frame;

NSUInteger numberOfCharsInLabel1 = NSNotFound;

NSUInteger numberOfCharactersThatTruncated = NSNotFound;

for (int i = [text length]; i >= 0; i--) {
    NSString *substring = [text substringToIndex:i];
    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:substring
                                                                         attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : font }];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(label1Frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGRect textFrame = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:size
                                                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                    context:nil];

    if (CGRectGetHeight(textFrame) <= CGRectGetHeight(label1Frame)) {
        numberOfCharsInLabel1 = i;

        numberOfCharactersThatTruncated = [text length] - numberOfCharsInLabel1;
        break;
    }
}

if (numberOfCharsInLabel1 == NSNotFound) {
    // TODO: Handle this case.
}

 label1.text = [text substringToIndex:numberOfCharsInLabel1];  // If you want to set character that label only can accept without truncating

//OR


label1.text = text;  //set full text with truncating


NSLog(@"Number of Truncated Characters %d",numberOfCharactersThatTruncated);


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Here `self.myLabel` is referencing outlet of label.

`numberOfCharactersThatTruncated` is your `desired output`.

this will return number of characters in label that are truncated.

**This will return totally truncated characters I mean if your string is `Hello there` and label is able to show `hell` then result should be `7` but you will see in label something like `h...` because label shows three dots when truncate. So, If you want to count the characters that are not displayed at all then you need to add `3` in your final output i.e,**

```
  numberOfCharactersThatTruncated = numberOfCharactersThatTruncated + 3;
```

**Update:**

My label's frame is : (27,75,93,56)

I have just set `top,leading,fixed height,fixed width` constraints.

Ans same code works like charm.

I think you are making mistakes in counting the characters. White space should be considered as one character. Then if your label shows three dots that means these three characters label can shows.

Example : your string is : how are you?

so total character is : 12

now for example your label shows : how a...

that means it shows 8 character (including .(dots))

So, `numberOfCharactersThatTruncated` will return 4.

If you are considering that `how a` are only visible characters and not considering `.` then you should add `3` to `numberOfCharactersThatTruncated`.

If you want to show only characters that can fit in label then use `label1.text = [text substringToIndex:numberOfCharsInLabel1];` this.

It will not show dot.

Cheers....:)

Comment: sorry for late response because my computer had problem. I have checked your solution but it won't calculate correct if my label have multiple lines

Comment: can you share the your demo. i also create a demo project and use your code but it calculate wrong

Comment: There is nothing new in my demo. just one label on viewController put through interface builder and taken outlet of it  and there is a `viewDidload` written in answer. but I haven't set constraint to label.

Comment: I'm using AutoLayout so I need to set the constraint

Comment: Actually i haven't set constraints when i have tested. so without constraint it should work!

Comment: can you modify your solution to make it work with autolayout then i can accept it. now when i design any layout, i alway use autolayout

Comment: I have set constraint to my label and same code works fine. check my update in answer.